# Apache library didnt include any jar files?

Tags: java

Could some of you explain why apache library didn't include any jar files. Did I mess something up, or am I missing something I should know. I've download libraries in the past and it has always worked properly.

I downloaded the library from apache's official website ->

https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/poi/release/src/poi-src-5.2.3-20220909.zip

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you grabbed the POI source ZIP file by mistake.

I think you want the binary poi-bin-5.2.3-20220909.zip instead.

https://archive.apache.org/dist/poi/release/bin/

A better idea would be to let [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi) manage your dependencies.